# Rx JS startsWith() operator resolves Promise's Result?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Consider an RxJs Operator Problem As

```
//emit (1,2,3)
const source = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3);
//start with 0
const example =  source.startWith(0);
//output: 0,1,2,3
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Now I want **startWith()** to be a result of a Promise.

```
// - 1
var pr = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => res(-1), 1000);
});
```

Promise Errors to be caught in the Subscriptions error block.

The Final output should look like

```
-1, 1, 2, 3
```

### ------------------------------------------------

**Attempt 1:** I tried putting in the promise but it does not get resolved.

```
const example =  source.startWith(pr);
```

**Attempt 2:**: I tried using async await but was stuck with the try catch block.

Comment: This is totally unclear. Please give the output you expect and what you have tried. Better yet, provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Well you can not do that with the of operator. Once you have called `of.subscribe`, the stream is started then closed. You can't append a new value to it without re-subscribing.

Comment: @Maryannah, const example =  source.startWith(0); adds a zero at the start. That's possible. What I want is to add a result from a promise, not a hardcoded value.

Comment: You can **NOT** use a promise to append a value to a stream. You **CAN** create a stream from a promise with all the desired values. But that will be a **SECOND** stream, not the same as the first one. Am I being clear enough ?

Comment: @Maryannah, Yes you are clear. **Now I want start With to be a result of a Promise.**  Is there any possible workaround to achieve this?

Comment: No there's not. You have to strart from the promise itself, [something like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-frost-607lz)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `concat()`. Worked well for me in a similar situation.

```js
import { concat, of } from 'rxjs';

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => /* process and resolve */);

const observable = of(1, 2, 3).pipe(
    /* Pipe whatever operator you need, but don't use `startWith()` */
);

const subscription = concat(promise, observable).subscribe(...);
```

> ⚠ Notice `concat` is imported from `rxjs` (not `rxjs/operators`).
>
> ⚠ Your pipes will only be applied once `observable` starts emitting. If you want to apply any pipes to your promise, you would have to wrap it with `from` like so: `from(promise)`.

#### TLDR - How does it work?

`concat` takes existing streams (observable / promise /iterable...) and emits their values sequentially. Every stream must complete before the next one starts emitting.

So... Essentially, the stream your getting is:

- resolved promise value
- 1
- 2
- 3

#### Examples and docs on `concat`:

[Official docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat)

[Learn RxJs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html)

Cheers and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You has two Observables, source and sourceAdd

```
const source = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3);
const sourceAdd;
yourPromise.then(res=>{
   sourceAdd=source.pipe(startWith(res));
   sourceAdd.subscribe(res=>{
   })
}
```